# How to select rows in a data.table matching simultaneously two conditions in another data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I have two data.tables `DT1` and `DT2`, with `DT1` possibly large and more columns than `DT2`. I want to select rows in `DT1` where two columns of `DT1` have exact matches in the same row of two columns in `DT2`. For example

```
DT1 = data.table(x=rep(c("b","a","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), z=1:9)
DT2 = data.table(f=c("a","b"), g=c(1,3))
```

The output, `DT1sub`, I'm looking for is

```
   x y z
1: a 1 4
2: b 3 2
```

My problem is, when I try to subset `DT1`, I also get those rows for which only one column matches

```
> DT1[x%in%DT2$f & y%in%DT2$g]
#    x y z
# 1: b 1 1
# 2: b 3 2
# 3: a 1 4
# 4: a 3 5
```

I could get my desired output, `DT1sub`, with a clunky `for` loop like

```
DT1sub<-c()
for (i in 1:2)
  DT1sub<-rbind(DT1sub,DT1[x==DT2$f[i] & y==DT2$g[i]])
DT1sub
```

but I was wondering if there was a smarter data.table version of this. This is probably straightforward, but I couldn't piece it together from the `example("data.table")`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for:

```
library(data.table)

DT1sub <- DT1[DT2, on = .(x = f, y = g)]
```

Output:

```
   x y z
1: a 1 4
2: b 3 2
```

This is basically a filtering join - it only keeps those rows in `x` that match anything in `f`, and the same for `y` and `g`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome! Consider accepting the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea is to use `setkey`.

```
library(data.table)

DT1 = data.table(x=rep(c("b","a","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), z=1:9)
DT2 = data.table(f=c("a","b"), g=c(1,3))

setkey(DT1, x, y)
setkey(DT2, f, g)

DT1[DT2]
#    x y z
# 1: a 1 4
# 2: b 3 2
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you very much, too! So much to learn with data.table!

Answer (score 1):

The above answers work great but I still prefer to use `merge()` for this task because its arguments are more expressive:

```
DT1sub <- merge(
  x = DT1, 
  y = DT2, 
  by.x = c('x', 'y'), by.y = c('f', 'g'), all.x = FALSE, all.y = FALSE)
```

Of course some of the arguments are redundant because they are set by default, but writing it out this way ensures you remember whether you've imposed an inner/outer join, etc.

Comment: Thank you, this is a helpful spelling out of the more shorthand code the other two answers give. To see that they all operate like merge operations it is useful to redefine `DT2` in my question with a third column, that will be appended to `DT1sub`. E.g. `DT2 = data.table(f=c("a","b"), g=c(1,3), k=c(1,2))`.